# postgresql use column name value when quoted with single quotes

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to update hstore key value with another table reference column. Syntax as simple as

```
SET misc = misc || ('domain' => temp.domain)
```

But I get error because everything in parenthesis should be quoted:

```
SET misc = misc || ('domain=>temp.domain')::hstore
```

But this actually inserts `temp.domain` as a string and not its value. How can I pass `temp.domain` value instead?

Comment: Does "temp.domain" mean a value in the "domain" column of table "temp"? If so, *which* value?

Comment: this only part of the query, which finishes with WHERE ev.id = temp.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate text with a subquery, and cast the result to type hstore.

```
create temp table temp (
  temp_id integer primary key, 
  domain text
);
insert into temp values (1, 'wibble');

select ('domain => ' || (select domain from temp where temp_id = 1) )::hstore as key_value
from temp
```

```
key_value
hstore
--
"domain"=>"wibble"
```

Updates would work in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, that did work perfectly. Although I'm quite astonished how complicated became such a simple task.